# Calling a function from another extended class

Tags: actionscript-3

I have my main stage, and I have two objects (blocks), these two objects both extend from the "Block" class. The "Block" class is NOT extended from the Main Class.

I would LIKE to call a function, in either the "Block" class or in it's subclasses, from the Main Stage Class. The functions will do slightly different things depending which object you are calling the function (Added different things, and different number of things to an array). What is the best way to implement this?

I am sorry I have no code to show right now, I am just attempting to sit down and do it now but feel quite lost.

Comment: Do you mean that both of these blocks should have the same function and even though they extend the same thing the functions should do two different things depending on which block calls it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure I follow so I'm going to assume you mean this.

You have a class called **Block**

You create two of these Block's and store them, possibly in an array from your base class.

```
//stage base class
var blockArray:Array = new Array()

private function createBlocks():void{

    var blockOne:Block = new Block(1); //passing in an int to block, could be anything but this 
                                       // will be used to do slightly different things

    var blockTwo:Block = new Block(2);
    blockArray.push(blockOne...blockTwo)
}
```

Now in your block class

```
//block class
class Block{
   var somethingDifferent:int; //this is where we will store the int you pass in when the blocks are made
   public function Block(aInt:int){
       somethingDifferent = aInt //grabbing the int
   }

   public function doSomething():void{
       trace(somethingDifferent); //will trace out the number passed
   }

}
```

Now back in your main class

```
//stage base class
private function doSomethingToBlocks():void{
    //lets call doSomething on each block
    Block(blockArray[0]).doSomething() //this will trace 1 because we passed that into the block in our array slot 0
    Block(blockArray[1]).doSomething() //this will trace 2
}
```

Hopefully this is what you're after

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is to define the function in the parent class and then to override the function in the subclass to do different things. Then, you can call the function on the various subclasses and it will do different things depending on the block.

A brief example:

Block class:

```
public function getBlockType():String
{
   return "I am a plain block";
}
```

First block subclass

```
public override function getBlockType():String
{
   return "I am a cool block";
}
```

Second block subclass:

```
public override function getBlockType():String
{
   return "I am an even cooler block";
}
```

Stage:

```
//add the first block
var coolBlock:CoolBlock = new CoolBlock();
addChild(coolBlock);

//add the second block
var coolerBlock:EvenCoolerBlock = new EvenCoolerBlock();
addChild(coolerBlock);

//call the functions
trace(coolBlock.getBlockType());//outputs "I am a cool block"
trace(coolerBlock.getBlockType());//outputs "I am an even cooler block"
```